# How can code be activated on click of a button in a Django view?

Tags: python, django, templates, django-views

I have a template that contains a button.

I have a view for this template in a view file.

How can a part of the code be activated when this button is clicked - which is in the template?

How can you make this as easy as possible?

How can code be activated on click of a button in a Django view?

```
def click_button_summ(request):
    context = {}
    if request.POST.get("button_table_summ") == "button_table_summ":
        ///code///
    return render(request, "click_button_summ.html", context)


    <div class="ui container">
        <div class="column">
            <button type="submit" class="ui button" name="button_table_summ" value="button_table_summ">Button</button>
        </div>
    </div>`
```

Comment: You should do `if "button_table_summ" in request.POST` instead.

Comment: unfortunately I already tried this
did not work

need something else

Comment: Is it your actual code you shared?

Answer (score 0):

In template:

```
<button id="choose-your-id-here" type="submit" class="ui button" name="button_table_summ" value="1">Button</button>
```

where value can be whatever you like, but ***ensure*** that all buttons have a unique value (so numbers are easiest -- and you don't actually use the value anyway) and are not the same as the name. With the solution above you can have multiple buttons on the same page:

```
<button id="choose-your-id-here" type="submit" class="ui button" name="button_table_foo" value="1">Button</button>

<button id="choose-your-id-here" type="submit" class="ui button" name="button_table_bar" value="2">Button</button>
```

and, in your one view (that handles everything), have code specific to each one with:

```
if request.POST.get("button_table_foo"):
    # code here specific to this button being pressed as form submission

if request.POST.get("button_table_bar"):
    # code here specific to this button being pressed as form submission
```

and/or you can put a formaction in your template to be handled by different views (as long as you have that view in your urls.py of course):

```
<button id="choose-your-unique-id" type="submit" class="ui button" name="button_table_summ" value="1" formaction="{% url 'valid url-in-urls.py-here' %}>Button</button>
```